# How to select and remove all the first consonants of a word and place them at the end of the word in python?

Tags: python, function, nested-loops

I want to remove all the first consonants of a word and place them at the end of the word

input -> `"step down"`

output -> `"epst ownd"`

this is my code so far:

```
def lang(text):
    alist=text.split() 
    vokaler="äåöaeiouÄÅÖAEIOU"
    retText=""
    for word in alist:
        nytext=""
        nytext_b=""
        n=0
        for tkn in word:
            if not tkn in vokaler:
                nytext+=tkn
                n+=1
            else:    
                for rest in word[n:]:
                    nytext_b+=rest
                    retText=nytext_b+nytext+"all"+" "

    return retText

print(lang("step down"))
```

Comment: So? What does your code do, and what did you expect it to instead?

Comment: Does it work as written?

Comment: The code as it is goes through every letter of a word. If it is a consonant it saves it to an empty variable. If it is a vowel then it runs through the rest of the word and saves it in another variable. Then i add them together into an empty third var. I dont know how to stop the loop from continuing after it has gone through the rest of the word

Comment: Then I suggest you learn more about [control flow](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html).

Comment: This is what i get: owndall. For some reason it skips the first word

Comment: What if the word starts with a vowel??  `...stop the loop from continuing...` - ```for tkn in word:``` will stop when the characters are exhausted.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you want to put every letter of the string to end then you can use following code:

```
  a="step down"
  l=a.split()
  print l
  data1=""
  for x in l:
     data=x[1:]+x[0:1]
     data1=data1+data

     data1=data1+" "
  print data1
```

output:

```
  teps ownd
```

Comment: Your code does not do what you say - `put every letter of the string to end`.  Also, OP stated every `first consonant` to the end.

Comment: Can you see the output which I given in post

Comment: Probably, because it is incorrect and only works for the given example and it is not solving the problem.

Comment: CAN YOU GIVE THE STRING WHICH IS NOT WORKING?@badc0re

Comment: Thank YOU Jack! Appreciate it... i confuse myself more than often :)

Comment: @Nash if this solves your problem, you need to revise your question and the expected output.

Comment: I apologize if the question was not clear. All i wanted to do was select all the consonants of a word up to the first vowel and then add them to the end of the word. Jacks code helped me understand what i had to do!